# Getting table info from Windguru with JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am doing a small app where I need to get the values of the wind speed throughout the day. I would like to use the Windguru first table to get the info I need, which is the day and hour and the wind speed. But for some reason, I am having trouble getting any text of each row, and I am not being able to find the solution. If someone could help me figure it out I would be thankful. Here is the peace of code I tried to use:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    String url_ericeira= "https://www.windguru.cz/9472";
    try {
        Document doc= Jsoup.connect(url_ericeira).get();
        Elements table = doc.select("table.tabulka");
        Elements rows= table.select("tr");

        for(int i=1;i<rows.size();i++){
            Element row= rows.get(i);
            Elements cols= row.select("td");
            System.out.println(cols.text());
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: CANT CONNECT");
    }
}
```

Also here is the link of the windguru site:
[WindGuru](https://www.windguru.cz/9472)

Comment: You can use API requests way for ex:- you request data using API call https://api.shakabay.com/api/offers/search?language=en&dist=30000&lat=39&lng=-9.4&sortBy=distance same way there are other API's available with different data.

Comment: yep - use the api, if you check whats going on in the network profiler in Chrome Dev Tools, you'll see a bunch of requests go out to `iapi.php` so it would seem the API is the correct solution. example: https://www.windguru.cz/int/iapi.php?q=station_data_last&id_station=2329&hours=3&avg_minutes=5&back_hours=0&vars=wind_avg&graph_info=0&WGCACHEABLE=150&_mha=e375ba02

Comment: Please only do this for personal use: https://www.windguru.cz/help.php?sec=terms